# Why is it that these prog-mode keybindings aren't working in emacs-lisp-mode?

Tags: debugging, emacs, elisp

I have a couple lines in my Emacs setup:

```
;; swap defaults
(define-key prog-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)
(define-key prog-mode-map (kbd "C-j") 'newline)
```

This works as expected in the couple of other programming modes that I tried. But in the Emacs Lisp mode, <kbd>RET</kbd> was still bound to `newline` and <kbd>C-j</kbd> was still bound to `newline-and-indent`. I still observed this confusing behavior even after moving the keybinding code to the very beginning of my Emacs initialization. If I create *separate* keybinding statements for Emacs Lisp's mode, I don't have any problems.

```
;; swap defaults for most programming modes
(define-key prog-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)
(define-key prog-mode-map (kbd "C-j") 'newline)

;; swap defaults in Emacs Lisp mode too
(define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)
(define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map (kbd "C-j") 'newline)
```

Why is this? If it matters, I'm using Emacs 24.3 on OS X 10.8.3.

P.S. I recently learned about `electric-indent-mode`, which probably accomplishes something very similar to these keybindings. However, the mystery still stands.

Comment: (guess), emacs-lisp-mode-map builts on `prog-mode-map`, and those two commands are already defined in `emacs-lisp-mode-map`. otherwords, definitions of those commands in `emacs-lisp-mode` overwrites the `prog-mode-map`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at the definition of `emacs-lisp-mode-map` in `lisp-modes.el`:

```
(defvar emacs-lisp-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap "Emacs-Lisp"))
        (menu-map (make-sparse-keymap "Emacs-Lisp"))
        (lint-map (make-sparse-keymap))
        (prof-map (make-sparse-keymap))
        (tracing-map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (set-keymap-parent map lisp-mode-shared-map)
    …
    map))
```

The key is the `set-keymap-parent` call.  Though Emacs Lisp Mode inherits from Prog Mode, its keymap does not inherit from `prog-mode-map`, but from another keymap defined in `lisp-modes.el`:

```
(defvar lisp-mode-shared-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map "\e\C-q" 'indent-sexp)
    (define-key map "\177" 'backward-delete-char-untabify)
    map)
  "Keymap for commands shared by all sorts of Lisp modes.")
```

This keymap also does not inherit from `prog-mode-map`, so bindings in `prog-mode-map` do indeed not have any effect in Emacs Lisp Mode.

This is arguably a bug in Emacs.

**Update:** [I wrote to the mailing list](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.devel/159878).

**Update 2:** [The corresponding bug report](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=14504)

**Update 3:** The bug has been fixed.  In a current snapshot build your key bindings should work as expected.  As a work around for earlier builds of Emacs you can use the following snippet in your `init.el`:

```
(unless (keymap-parent lisp-mode-shared-map)
  (set-keymap-parent lisp-mode-shared-map prog-mode-map))
```

Now `lisp-mode-shared-map` will inherit from `prog-mode-map`, effectively replicating the bug fix.